# problem when i try printing sales invoice

Tags: c#, sql-server, crystal-reports, entity-framework-6

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    hesham2020Entities2 db = new hesham2020Entities2();
    string u;
    u = textBox1.Text.Trim();
    var y = from v in db.inv_detail
            from s in db.invoice_head 
            where s.invno==u
            select new
                {v.unit,v.qty,v.p_no,v.description,v.price,v.tot_price,s.invno,s.customer_id,s.inv_dat,s.po_no,s.total,s.currency};
    CrystalReport6 crt = new CrystalReport6();
    crt.SetDataSource(y);
    crv9.Refresh();
    crt.SetParameterValue(0, comboBox2.SelectedItem);
    crt.SetParameterValue(1, comboBox3.SelectedItem);
    //crt.SetParameterValue(2, textBox1.Text);
    crv9.ReportSource = crt;
    crv9.Refresh();
}
```

when i try to print this invoice if the invoice details contain 3 rows it printed 9 rows, 
that mean every row printed 3 times, but when the invoice details contain 1 row it printed 1 row. i can not know the reason of the error

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the join between inv_detail and invoice_head.
Basically you are doing a cartesian product, you should try something like:

```
from db.invoice_head 
join db.inv_detail
on [...]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the following code can help you, maybe you forgot to use join correctly.

I used Id property for Join

```
var y = (from v in db.inv_detail
                 join  s in db.invoice_head on v.HeaderId equals s.Id
            where s.Id == u
                 select new
            {
                v.Id
            }).ToList();
```

or

```
var query = db.inv_detail
            .Join(db.invoice_head, 
                post => post.HeaderId,       
                meta => meta.Id,  
                (post, meta) => new { Post = post, Meta = meta }) 
            .Where(postAndMeta => postAndMeta.Post.Id == u);
```

Comment: this is not success i tried the above code but it always repeat every row three times

Comment: Do you add `Join` and and check relation equal by `on v.HeaderId equals s.Id`?

Comment: @hesham1703: When you debug the code, `y` have every row three times.

Comment: @ hesham1703:Why `crv9` to `Refresh` twice? You may not need the first `Refresh` and why you didn't add the `crv9.ViewerCore.ReportSource = reportDoc;` instead of the `crv9.ReportSource = crt;`

Comment: this not effective i tried every thing i use join ,i stop report refresh but the problem is the same the  one row invoice print one row , the two rows invoice printed 4 rows

Comment: You can edit the task and add the join code, your classes and the data. Thanks

Comment: var y = (from x in db.inv_detail
                     join s in db.invoice_head on x.inv_no equals s.invno
                     where s.invno== u
                     where x.inv_no==u
                     select new { x.unit, x.qty, x.p_no, x.description, x.price, x.tot_price,s.customer_id, s.invno,s.inv_dat,s.po_no,s.total }).ToList();

Comment: i do the above code but noway the same problem is still